# using registerShutdownHook() in the Spring Framework

Tags: java, xml, spring

I am following this tutorial online to the letter.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_life_cycle.htm

But I get the errors when using Eclipse
when I get to this line:
context.registerShutdownHook();

Eclipse says:

"Multiple markers at this line
  - Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete 
     Assignment
  - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
  - The method registerShutdownHook() is undefined for the type 
     ApplicationContext"

I am following this tutorial exactly. All of my variable names are exactly the same.My code is exactly the same as his. I am not sure what is wrong.

What am I doing wrong, what can be done to fix this so that I can continue the tutorial.

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

        HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld)context.getBean("helloWorld");
        obj.getMessage();
        context.registerShutdownHook();
    }
}
```

Comment: `code` package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp{
 public static void main (String []args)
 {
  ApplicationContext context =
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
  
  
  HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");
  obj.getMessage();
  context.registerShutdownHook();

  
 }
 
 
 
 
}  `code`

Comment: as I said you are using `ApplicationContext` istead of `AbstractApplicationContext`

Comment: I guess you were not quite following the tutorial "to the letter". I made the exact same mistake, so thanks for posting.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For the error it seems that context is a object of [`ApplicationContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html), whereas in tutorial it should be an object of [`AbstractApplicationContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html)

I am just guessing that you wrote this

```
public class MainApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      ApplicationContext context = 
                          new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");//error here

      HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");
      obj.getMessage();
      context.registerShutdownHook();
   }
}
```

Comment: Okay what import is needed to use AbstractApplicationContext? Right now it is telling me that it cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: simply press control+shift+o if you are using eclipse, or `import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext`

Comment: How can I use it with SpringApplication.run(...)?

Answer (score 3):

You should use AbstractApplicationContext instead of ApplicationContext according to the spring documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-nature

```
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public final class Boot {

 public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
  AbstractApplicationContext ctx
      = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String []{"beans.xml"});

  // add a shutdown hook for the above context... 
  ctx.registerShutdownHook();

  // app runs here...

  // main method exits, hook is called prior to the app shutting down...
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I also got the same issue. I solved it using this way.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Bean.xml");
    HelloWorld obj =(HelloWorld)context.getBean("helloWorld");
    obj.getMessage();
    ((AbstractApplicationContext) context).registerShutdownHook();
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to  import (import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that worked for me.

```
package arjun;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

                AbstractApplicationContext context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
                context.registerShutdownHook();
                Triangle triangle=(Triangle) context.getBean("triangle");
                triangle.draw();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

//use this line,

((AbstractApplicationContext) ctx).registerShutdownHook();

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated solution:

```
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;  

((AbstractApplicationContext) appContext).registerShutdownHook();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AnnotationConfigApplicationContext instead of xml based config then in place of initialising context as

```
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BeanConfig.class);
```

use

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BeanConfig.class);
```

[Thanks to the explanation in the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17270211/18301333)