# Closing a Spring ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring

When I create a new Spring ApplicationContext, for example via

```
final ApplicationContext ac = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfiguration.class);
```

Eclipse (STS 3.2.0) will mark it as a potential resource leak, complaining it is never closed ('Resource leak: 'ac' is never closed).

So far, so good. Then I tried to look into the issue, and was not able to find a `close()` or `shutdown()` or similar method that would even allow me to close the `ApplicationContext`. Is this an Eclipse warning go haywire, intended design or am I missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring ApplicationContext - Resource leak: 'context' is never closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184059/spring-applicationcontext-resource-leak-context-is-never-closed)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You declare `ac` as `ApplicationContext` which doesn't define a `close()` method. Instead of that use any super-type of `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` that extends `Closeable` (e.g. `ConfigurableApplicationContext`) providing the `close()` method you need to release all resources.

Answer (score 5):

If you use Java 7 you can use the try-with-resources statement to do the work for you

```
try (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ac = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(...))
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, interface `ApplicationContext` doesn't have `close()` method, but child classes [`AbstractApplicationContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html) and [`GenericApplicationContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/GenericApplicationContext.html) have `close()` and `destroy()`. So, I suggest to use them instead. Also there is useful method `registerShutdownHook()`.

Answer (score 1):

Downcast your ApplicationContext to ConfigurableApplicationContext which defines close() method:

((ConfigurableApplicationContext)appCtx).close();

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14424009/466363